# Hasura GraphQL how to group query by month and year?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Is it possible in GraphQL or Hasura to group the results by month or year? I'm currently getting the result list back as a flat array, sorted by the `date` attribute of the model. However, I'd like to get back 12 subarrays corresponding to each month of the year.

Comment: Was wondering the same thing today. Shame there's not a better solution for this :/

Answer (score 3):

From docs - natively **not supported**.

[Derived data or data transformations](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine#derived-data-or-data-transformations) leads to [views](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/views.html#example-group-by-and-then-aggregate). Using [PostgreSQL EXTRACT Function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-extract/) you can have separate month field from data ...  but still as flat array.

Probably with some deeper customization you can achieve desired results ... but graphql [tree, arrays] structures are more for embedding not for view ...

How many records you're processing? Hundreds? Client side conversion (done easily from apollo client data on react component/container [view] level) may be good enough [especially with extracted month field].

PS. You can have many results groupped in arrays if you 'glue' many queries (copies, each month filtered) on top level ... but probably not recommended solution.